# Ubuntu 12.04 not starting

Tags: 12.04, boot, boot-failure

I have upgraded to 12.04 a few days ago and it was working just fine yesterday. I just tried to boot Ubuntu now for a couple of tries and it gets to he 5 purple dots and stops. Not sure what to do. It is on a dual boot so I have windows but that is not exactly ideal.

Comment: It might be a corrupted installation. Why not try reinstalling?

Comment: How can I reinstall? Do I just remove the partition it is on?

Answer (score 0):

Make a bootable USB, boot from it and click on install. During the steps, when it asks for the partition, select the partition you already have Ubuntu installed on. :)